# Ultra Low Current Boosting

Tags: current

So I am new to electronics, but I'm trying to figure out if I can boost current from 10mA to 100mA. I researched and found a current booster called the lmc6001 that boosts from 10mA to 30, which is not what I need. Would I need a booster for this or is it possible with some components? It is also worth noting that I boosted my voltage with a step up voltage booster to 2.35v. So, I need something that is able to boost only current, is this possible?

Comment: "I boosted my voltage" And that would be why you're getting so little current.

Comment: You can't create power.  Any circuit that increases current must also reduce voltage, or get power from an external source.

Comment: What you want to boost, voltage or current.? You can't boost both, unless you use amplifier.

Comment: Or sacrifice time for either of them. Technically it's energy you can't get more of, not power, but for most applications pulsing power is unsuitable.

Comment: I want to boost both voltage and current. I found a way to boost my voltage to 2.35v but I was unaware that it would decrease current. Is there anyway to increase both?

Comment: As stated above, unless you add another source of energy, there is no way to increase both. It is physically impossible, just like a perpetual motion machine.

Comment: draw a block diagram of what you want, including where you're going to get the extra power from (battery, power supply, whatever) and then we can suggest ways to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buy a transistor. Use an emitter follower circuit. You will get a 0.7V voltage drop, but you will get all the current you need.

[image]

Comment: This is cool! Luckily, dropping .7v will not have any effect on the circuit, it actually makes it better because my 2.35v was already too high. I have one question though, could you explain what the collector is doing?

Comment: collector is attached to supply voltage

Answer (score 1):

you can use this Ic too . this don't decrease your voltage and have perfect current boos like 10000 time grater but it need dual power supply the full name of Ic is:

((ADA4891-1))

and it's cost is lower than 0.5 $

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I can only have one power supply..

Comment: A 741 can't put out much more than 20mA, certainly not 100mA.

Comment: ok but you can use it single now